# Can you make sense of this C pointer code?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, visual-c++, pointers

I have this snippet of C code that uses pointers in a very confusing way.

```
   // We first point to a specific location within an array..
   double* h = &H[9*i];
   int line1 = 2*n*i;
   int line2 = line1+6;

   // ..and then access elements using that pointer, somehow..
   V[line1+0]=h[0]*h[1];
   V[line1+1]=h[0]*h[4] + h[3]*h[1];
```

What's happening here? how do I write something equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really write something equivalent in C# because you don't have pointers there (except by invoking `unsafe` code) - to get an element from a C# array, you need an array ref and an index, and you index into the array.

You can, of course, do the same with a C array. We convert the C pointer-arithmetic into C array-indexing:

```
int h_index = 9 * i;
int line1 = 2 * n * i;
int line2 = line1 + 6;

V[line1 + 0] = H[h_index] * H[h_index + 1];
V[line1 + 1] = H[h_index] * H[h_index + 4] + H[h_index + 3] * H[h_index + 1];
```

And then we have something that can be used pretty much verbatim in C#.

Answer (score 2):

`&H[9*i] == (H + 9*i)`, thus you can replace uses of `h[x]` with `H[9*i+x]`.  The rest should be straightforward.